# Move directory content from local file system to HDFS using Java

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a source directory(`/home/src`) in local filesystem containing 2 files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

I want to copy them to destination directory(`/user/dest`) in `HDFS` through code.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;
```

When I use `FileUtil` API to move the content from local `src` to hdfs `dest`, it is moving the `src` directory as well.

```
FileUtil.copy("/home/src", fs, "/user/dest", true, conf);
```

Is there a way, where I can move only the directory contents from `src` to `dest` using `Java` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hadoop` has build in `API`s that can be used to copy from local to `hdfs`
You just need to `import` necessary libraries and call the `apis` as below

This will copy the `src` folder from local to `/user/dest/` of `hdfs` 
If individual files are to be copied follow the following way : by listing the files and copying individual files (we can filter files too if we want)

```
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

 FileSystem file = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())

File[] sourceFiles = new File("/home/src").listFiles();
            if(sourceFiles != null) {
                for(File f: sourceFiles) {
                    //we can filter files if needed here
                    file.copyFromLocalFile(true, true, new Path(f.getPath()), new Path("/user/dest"));
                }
            }
```

I hope this is helpful